# Django - after sign-in template don't know that user is authenticated

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-authentication

Below code probably works (no errors present):

**views.pl**

```
class SignInView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "signin.html")

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.POST.get('username', '')
        pass = request.POST.get('password', '')

        user = authenticate(username=user, password=pass)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Bad user.")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

....but in template:

```
{% user.is_authenticated %}
```

is not True. So I don't see any functionality for authenticated user.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like:

```html
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <!-- code for authenticated user -->
{% else %}
    <!-- code for unauthenticated user -->
{% endif %}
```

I could see another problem in views, `pass` is a reverse keyword in Python, you should also change variable name.

Comment: Why with request in front? Does my version is wrong? I have seen it in many examples.

Comment: @PrertoQuebas basically, the main thing is that you are missing `if`. Ya it also works for `user.is_authenticated`.

Comment: @PrertoQuebas so is it still not working?

Comment: Now is OK, I had different problem with front end file. Now everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You should do like `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` or `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

Comment: Why? Does my version is wrong?

Comment: because `user` was not defined in the template context

Comment: For me work both versions. Check Sunderam Dubey's comment above.